# How do I print an individual field in block.html.twig?

Tags: theming, 8, blocks

I have tried as many options as I can imagine but none of them prints anything except:

```
{{ content }}
```

However, I require individual fields for more control over theming.

I am using a custom block type and the following function.

```
function THEME_theme_suggestions_block_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  // Block suggestions for custom block bundles.
    if (isset($variables['elements']['content']['#block_content'])) {
    array_splice($suggestions, 1, 0, 'block__bundle__' . $variables['elements']['content']['#block_content']->bundle());
  }
}
```

The template is working fine. I can hard code some random text and it is displayed. I just can't display the field values.

How do I print an individual field in block.html.twig?

Comment: What kind of individual fields do you need? Are they part of the block content (like a displayed node in a block) or part of the block itself (like its title)?

Comment: fields added to a custom blocks type.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a field called field_test you schould be able to do like this

```
{{ content.field_test }}
```

and if you want to only print the value you can do like:

```
{{ content.field_test[0] }}
```

If you want to see what is inside the field you can do like this:

```
{{ kint(content.field_test) }}
```

But only if you have `Devel` module installed and have `Devel Kint` enabled you should be able to do that.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: thank you for your reply. while these options work in node.html.twig they do not work in block.html.twig for fields added to a custom block. this includes core fields like body. for example {{ content.body }} does not work.

Comment: there is a lot of output. which part specifically should i be looking for?

Comment: yep this solution is a pretty good one, clear your caches and try with something like that to get a lighter result.

<ol>
  {% for key, value in _context  %}
    <li>{{ key }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ol>

Comment: field_image and body. i checked in the kint arrays for these fields and i do not see any reference as far as how to display value from the template file

Comment: for example {{ kint(content.body) }} or {{ kint(content.field_image) }} return NULL on kint output

Comment: yes when i {{kint(content)}} i see output. i see field names. but if i kint a field name eg {{ kint(content.field_image) }} i see NULL as output

Comment: it is an array and it is not empty .. it has (17).

Comment: It's likely that the fields are not configured in the display (Manage Display) on the block type.

Comment: the fields are configured correctly in Manage Display. They appear fine with {{ content }}. It is my understanding after much research getting individual field values from custom blocks is not really possible in D8.

Comment: Its entirely possible, I've done it. `{{ content.field_name }}`.

Comment: I believe it has something to do with render functions, because I can confirm simply {{ content.field_name }} does not necessarily work.